# Move files having one or two digits in name at certain point

Tags: python, regex, bash, mv

Let's say I have a folder full of files with a name in the format `foo<number1>.bar.o<number2>`. `<number1>` can consist of `1`, `2` or `3` digits.

Now if I, for some odd reason, would want to move only the files at which `<number1>` consists of `1` or `2` digits, but not `3`, I would write a `python` script:

```
#!/bin/python
import glob, shutil, re
for f in glob.glob("*.bar.o*"):
    print f
    numbers = map(int, re.findall('\d+', f))
    print numbers
    if numbers[0] < 100:
        shutil.move(f, "dir/" + f)
```

The question now: How can, if, this be done in less code, for example in one line (max 80 characters)?

Would prefer a solution usable in a `bash` shell.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this in bash yourself? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @TomFenech At the `bash` part, really. My question was based more on interest in other solutions, knowing that the code I spent roughly 10 minutes on is far from optimal in size. I do now see the flaw that it is not really a question, or meant as a question, but am nevertheless still interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless I'm mistaken about what you mean:

```
mv foo[0-9][0-9].bar* /wherever/you/like
```

will catch 2 digit numbers

For either you could do:

```
 mv $(ls |egrep "foo[0-9]{1,2}.bar") /wherever/you/like
```

Comment: You might try using `{0..99}` to catch all one and two digit numbers, instead of `[0-9][0-9]`.

Comment: oops, yeah that will only catch 2 digit numbers, not 1

Comment: @hgazibara While it works, it also gives errors if certain numbers in that range cannot be found...

Comment: @TheJustist Then you can either make `mv` fail silently or use pipe to first find all files matching the pattern and then move only those which were found.

Comment: put a more comprehensive option.

Answer (score 0):

To match `foo<number1>.bar.o<number2>`

```
for filename in *.bar.o*; do

    # 1. with a shell regex
    [[ $filename =~ ^foo[[:digit:]]{1,2}\.bar\.o[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && echo $filename

    # 2. with expanded globbing: shopt -s extglob
    [[ $filename == foo[[:digit:]]?([[:digit:]]).bar.o+([[:digit:]]) ]] && echo $filename

done
```